# Allow null values to be added to list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-types

i have removed all unnecessary variables andtried to focus directly on the problem at hand. I have a variable that can return null values:

```
var ppl = from p in xyz.new_ppl
          select new
          {
              p.name
          };
```

I query it and add it to a list:

```
foreach (var peeps in ppl)
{
    peopleList.Add(peeps.name);
    peopleNames = peopleList;
}
```

This works when i add a where clause to check before the select statement to check for null values using this statement

```
where p.name != null
```

What i want to be able to do is allow null values to be added. so i tried firstordefault but that didnt work

```
name = p.name.FirstorDefault()
```

the error says that i can't cast a char to string. peopleNames is a setter, getter method of type string. Any workaround or solution?

Comment: Why is this `peopleNames = peopleList;` inside the loop ?

Comment: What its the error you get when you run your original code? Ignore the p.name.FirstOrDefault() stuff and the error you get when you use it; that's not what you want anyways.

Comment: @HackedByChinese I'm away from that machine now but I was getting a null pointer exception. When I checked the data I noticed that peeps.name has one null value that I still want to pass to the list.

Comment: Errror reason is obvious add more detail for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would you like to try it like this?

```
var ppl = from p in xyz.new_ppl
          select new
          {
              p == null ? null : p.name
          };
```

Comment: @abatishchev I'll definetly give it a try when I have access to the other computer.

Comment: @John: Actually that's mono's answer (avatar to the right) :) I just edited it (avatar to the left)

Comment: @mono68: just tried, didn't work I get an invalid anonymous type member declarator error. Any other suggestions

Comment: After going back and looking at this question that i asked a while back, the conclusion is that this is the correct answer for linq to sql and linq to entities. it does not however work in my application where i use linq to crm. Maybe because of the nested relationships within the entities.

Answer (score 2):

```
from p in xyz.new_ppl
select p.name;
```

Comment: @ aba: In stackoverflow forum, try to give the explanation for your answer.This might be helpful for new users.

Comment: @aba thanks for your reply but as i mentioned i oversimplified the question. I need to retrieve more than one value say p.name, p.age, etc...I think  I tried this but eventually relaized that I have to create anonymous variables to retrieve multiple attributes but I will check later for sure

Answer (score 0):

When you do `p.name.FirstorDefault()` that means that you try to get a first character of string `p.name`. So compiler error is correct (thought I have no idea why it cannot implicitly convert character to string -- but that's another story :) )

But if you want nulls to be added as well, why not to just remove `where p.name != null`?

Comment: nulls don't get added if i remove the where p.name !=null. I get a null pointer exception. I can't seem to figure this out so i handled the null values by setting an empty string variable in place of all null roww values.

Comment: what type is `peopleList` of? could you paste stack trace and exception message?

Comment: People List is of type string. I currently don't have access to the code. What i concluded is in the select new { x= p.name, y = p.age...etc } if one of the attributes say p.age is null as as the case for me it throws a null exception. i tried handling it in every way possible  by doing something like y == null ? null : p.age or y = p.age ?? "null", so on and so forth to no avail. The only thing that worked is to actually include where p.age != null, that way it skips the whole row and goes to the next even though p.name contains data. I'll paste the stack trace as soon as I can